# Slope compensation of MAX17498

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, compensation

I want to use [MAX17498](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17498A-MAX17498C.pdf) in boost mode.

I have a problem setting the slope compensation. The slope (as I understand) is the gradient of the inductor's current ramp. The unit is [A/s] or [A/us]. However, the MAX17498's datasheet requires it as [mV/us] (*S_E*)

[image]

I guess that the MAX17498's current sensor characteristic missing to calculate this value.

How to calculate the slope resistor's value of MAX17498?

Comment: It's inadequately explained in the spec, but Maxim goes into more detail in this app note.  https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN5587.pdf

Comment: The slope compensation is also discussed in AN5503; for DCM operation, no added compensation is discussed but it is discussed in CCM mode operation. https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/5/5503.html

Comment: [app-note 5503](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/5/5503.html) mentions that the current sensor resistor (Rcs) is 0.5Ω for MAX1498B/C